# Mulesoft - Force exception according to statusCode

Tags: exception, salesforce, mule, throw

I've implemented a Mule flow that reads CSV files and insert the records into Salesforce using a batch.

To manage the errors I have created a step that only accepts failed records.

I've tried modifying the original values so that it fails and proving that it works properly.

The Salesforce response message is a JSON containing a field called statusCode with the following value: `INVALID_TYPE_ON_FIELD_IN_RECORD`.

However Mule does not recognize it as an error and does not fail so it never enters the Step of failed records.

[image]

How can I modify this? Should I change it in Salesforce or add the statusCode cases in Error Mapping?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Mule 4 you can use raiser-error to force an error. Then you just need to define what expression to trigger your expression:

```
#[sizeOf((payload.errors default [])) > 0]
```

or

```
#[payload.errors[0].statusCode=='INVALID_TYPE_ON_FIELD_IN_RECORD']
```

etc.

Example using choice router:

```
<choice doc:name="successful?">
            <when expression="#[sizeOf((payload.errors default [])) > 0]">
                <raise-error type="APP:INVALID_TYPE_ON_FIELD_IN_RECORD" />
            </when>
        </choice>
```

Alternative to controlling flow with errors is setting the acceptExpression on the batch step with the same expression:

```
<batch:step name="step1" acceptExpression="#[sizeOf((payload.errors default [])) > 0]">
```

Comment: Thank you very much ! However, it is not possible to use payload when I have the Salesforce component in a Batch Aggregator. How can I fix this?

Comment: you can still use payload in batch aggregator, however your payload will be a collection. You could use foreach scope to iterate it or iterate within the expression it self maybe something like #[sizeOf(flatten(payload..errors default [])) > 0]